# Blueprint.js dynamic $ns variable in scss

Tags: sass, blueprintjs

I'm using Blueprint.js v3.x and have been making use of the [SASS variables](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/develop/packages/core/src/common/_variables.scss#L10). I want to leverage the `$ns` variable, but my app is in dark mode. The `$ns` variable is set to `bp3 !default;` on line 10 of the file above, which from what I understand means I can set it to a different value in my `app.scss`. It would be fine, then, to just set `$ns: bp3-dark;` and use this variable that way. However, in the future I want to support a dark/light mode switch; how can I, following best practice, dynamically set `$ns` to be the correct value based on said switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further consideration, it seems that I am not entirely clear on the fundamentals of *why* the `$ns` variable exists: rather than trying to use it to reference whether the app is in dark or light mode, it makes more sense to use it thus (SCSS):

```
.app {
  .#{$ns}-dark {
    /* set the background color, any other required setup */
    ...
    & .my-button-group.#{$ns}-button-group {
      /* override anything you might want for the element.bp3-button-group
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially, the `$ns` variable is used to point to `bp3` to allow for future-proofing of your SASS. Changing it to `bp3-dark` or any other value would defeat this purpose.

Comment: Blueprint author/maintainer here. You are correct, it is meaningless to override the `$ns` variable to a different value, and I actually [removed the ability to do this recently](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/pull/5260). You _should_ be using the `$ns` variable in your Sass/Less code anywhere you wish to target Blueprint components for (ideally rare) style overrides, and that should future-proof your style code for upcoming major versions of the library.